# How can i solve Magento Out of memory Fatal error?

Tags: magento, xampp, out-of-memory

Magento 1.9.x with xampp-win32-7.0.4 showing following type error randomly

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 14680064) (tried to allocate 790528 bytes) in lib\Less\Parser.php on line 3719
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 134217728) (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in lib\Varien\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php on line 74
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228
```

I try as following link but nothing happen

https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/magento-fatal-error-out-of-memory-allocated-14680064-tried-to-allocate-1245184-bytes/

Comment: Ok, but does numbers of allocated memory change after increasing memory_limit in .htaccess?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity , i don't no actually magento or xampp or other  problem

Comment: @matinict - What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to increase the memory limit to 512 in your Magentos root folder .htaccess. Just find the following lines and adjust the value for memory_limit:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>

    ############################################
    ## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 512M
```

If you still run out of memory, there might be another problem in your Magento installation that consumes so much.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to index.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', 256M);
```

If the problem still comes increase the limit.